# Changing of text on button not permanent

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I have four buttons in a single view, with texts "A", "B", "X", "Y" on them respectively. I expected to see the texts of btnA and btnB change respectively when I pressed on btnX and btnY respectively and then both of btnA and btnB turn green. Instead, when I pressed btnA, "A" changed to "1" and immediately changed back to "A" again. But btnB changed to "2" permanently as expected.

This problem may seem simple but I just can't get the expected result. I just started to learn Swift. Please help me. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnX: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnY: UIButton!

    @IBAction func btnXPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        btnA.titleLabel?.text = "1"
        check()
    }

    @IBAction func btnYPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        btnB.titleLabel?.text = "2"
        check()
    }

    func check() {
        if ((btnA.titleLabel?.text)! == "1") && ((btnB.titleLabel?.text)! == "2") {
            btnA.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            btnB.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try btnA.setTitle("1", for: .normal) and for every button same way

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. I also changed "btnA.titleLabel?.text)!" to "btnA.currentTitle" in check(). It works perfectly! Thanks : )